# Complex table pivoting in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I say this is complex, it might actually be stupidly easy. I know how `pivot_wider` works but the fact that there are multiple iterations of the same person, where I want their multiple instances separated into different rows, confuses me.

I have the below table, in long format

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(
  statusId = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  creationDate = c('2022-09-16 14:56:14.226 UTC', '2022-09-27 20:29:16.277 UTC', '2022-09-21 13:33:18.879 UTC', '2022-09-12 00:42:44.889 UTC', '2022-09-27 19:06:34.617 UTC', '2022-09-01 07:29:08.938 UTC', '2022-09-16 15:56:27.437 UTC', '2022-09-12 16:22:10.988 UTC', '2022-09-22 15:28:09.581 UTC', '2022-10-03 14:38:46.905 UTC', '2022-09-30 11:29:48.761 UTC', '2022-09-25 21:27:42.551 UTC', '2022-09-20 08:11:01.216 UTC'),
  Person = c('Person_1', 'Person_1', 'Person_2', 'Person_1', 'Person_2', 'Person_4', 'Person_3', 'Person_3', 'Person_4', 'Person_1', 'Person_1', 'Person_1', 'Person_1')
)

# Print the data frame
df

   statusId                creationDate   Person
1         1 2022-09-16 14:56:14.226 UTC **Person_1**
2         1 2022-09-27 20:29:16.277 UTC **Person_1**
3         2 2022-09-21 13:33:18.879 UTC Person_2
4         2 2022-09-12 00:42:44.889 UTC Person_1
5         2 2022-09-27 19:06:34.617 UTC Person_2
6         2 2022-09-01 07:29:08.938 UTC Person_4
7         1 2022-09-16 15:56:27.437 UTC Person_3
8         2 2022-09-12 16:22:10.988 UTC Person_3
9         2 2022-09-22 15:28:09.581 UTC Person_4
10        1 2022-10-03 14:38:46.905 UTC **Person_1**
11        2 2022-09-30 11:29:48.761 UTC Person_1
12        2 2022-09-25 21:27:42.551 UTC Person_1
13        2 2022-09-20 08:11:01.216 UTC Person_1
```

I want to find the distribution of the days between any given person being statusId 1, and then becoming statusId 1 again. So, for example, I have highlighted `Person_1`. We can see that on the 2022-09-16 they were statusId 1, and then again on 2022-09-27. This is 11 days. The same person was statusId 1, again, on the 2022-10-03. So, there were 6 days on this instance (the time between their last statusId 1 and the most recent one). I want to ignore the other statuses in between.

So, I think, if we take Person_1 as an example, I think the table should be pivoted to look like below.

```
    Person delay
1 Person_1    11
2 Person_1     6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  filter(statusId == 1) |>
  mutate(creationDate = as.Date(creationDate)) |>
  arrange(Person, creationDate) |>
  group_by(Person) |>
  mutate(delay = creationDate - lag(creationDate)) |>
  filter(!is.na(delay)) |>
  select(delay)
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   Person [1]
  Person   delay  
  <chr>    <drtn> 
1 Person_1 11 days
2 Person_1  6 days
```

Comment: thanks for this. It answers my question so I have marked it as such. I do actually have a follow on question, though, if that's okay?

What if I wanted to filter by instances where the first instance of the status is before x date, but allow subsequent instances to be after this date?

In short, I am trying to calculate churn and statusId 1 is return, 2 is declined (on invitations).

I know the probability of them never coming back (statusId 1) goes up as time goes on.